# MP4 muxer для h.265 кодека

Tags: c, видео, mp4, freertos, mediacodec

Всем привет. Ищу библиотеку на С для записи MP4 файла. На вход подаются аудио\видео фреймы, на выходе mp4 файл. Кодек сжатия видео h.265, аудио - AAC
OS: RTOS
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: а `ffmpeg` банально взять не хочешь? или слишком жирно?

Comment: если бы система была под линукс, я бы использовал ffmpeg, но под RTOS его надо компилить, не факт что получится и хз, сколько времени займет. Ну и жирно тоже, мне ведь надо готовые ауди-видео фреймы "просто" упаковать в контейнер и не более того.

Comment: Кстати, а могу ли я видео сжатое 265 кодеком положить в avi контейнер? Для записи файла на SD карту не обязательно ведь использовать AVI?

Comment: из гугла: [libmp4v2](https://code.google.com/archive/p/mp4v2/) и [форк](https://github.com/sergiomb2/libmp4v2) чуть посвежее; [minimp4](https://github.com/lieff/minimp4)... и не вижу причин, почему бы благородным донам не закатать h256 в avi... хотя, если контейнер не важен, то ИМХО матрёшка была бы более естественным выбором...

Comment: Контейнер не важен, главное простота реализации.